# X is out in the sentence or take X off inside sentence

Tags: word-usage

My question is about using any of the following synonyms properly to talk about a grammar explanation.

Which is better?

> X is out in the sentence.

or:

> Take X off inside sentence.

Answer (score 1):

One of best ways to say this would be:

> Remove X from the sentence.

For example, a [website](https://www.glassdoor.com/blog/10-words-and-phrases-that-make-you-look-like-an-amateur/) offering some writing advice says:

> **Remove this phrase** and simply say what’s on your mind.

You could also use the verb *eliminate*:

> Eliminate X from the sentence.

Comment: +1 for using verbs and not phrasal verbs. Explaining grammar is quite formal, and phrasal verbs don't feel that appropriated...